# How to change iCloud ID?

Tags: ipad, icloud

Hello I need to change email address on my iCloud on my iPad but I don’t know how My e-mail box has been hacked and I had to change it I managed to change my Apple ID and when I checked my “iCloud account information” on iPad it’s showing my new email address yet on iCloud icon and next to my name there’s still my old email? How can I change it? Is my old email address still connected to my iCloud account? How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Sorry, but this is too confused to try to extract what happened & exactly what you did. You cannot 'change' an Apple ID. You can change the email address associated with it, but not the ID itself. See https://support.apple.com/HT202667

Answer (score 1):

YES, you can change the email address associated with the Apple ID. The Apple ID is literally the email address (don't pay attention to the previous answer...)! It sounds like you created an ADDITIONAL Apple ID instead of updating the email address on your current Apple ID.

Navigate to appleid.apple.com and login with your 'old' Apple ID email address, from here you will be able to update to your new email. However, you would also need to follow this process to login to appleid.apple.com with the NEW address and assign this a "dummy" email address so that you can assign the "new" email to your current Apple ID so that you retain all purchases and content associated with your iCloud account.